# NSURLConnectionDelegate works on iOS 9 and 10?

Tags: ios, ios9, nsurlconnection, ios10

According to the below developer site post:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlconnectiondelegate?language=objc

below methods of the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` is deprecated from iOS 8:

```
connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:

connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:
```

but I am still using them in iOS 9 and iOS 10 and OS also call them. Does some one have any idea how they work if they are deprecated?

Comment: if you target iOS SDK older than 9(7, 8) it will work, if you support iOS 9+ they won't.

Comment: "deprecated" means that you should not use them, but it's still suported. But behavior in future OS releases may cause issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecation means that they are planning to remove it. So it's not the removal of an API but the announcement that it will be removed in the future but is still available. 
As a rule of thumb you can expect that 2 major releases after deprecation an api will get removed.

Wikipedia explains it as:

> In several fields, deprecation is the discouragement of use of some
>   feature, design or practice; typically because it has been superseded
>   or is no longer considered safe – but without completely removing it
>   or prohibiting its use.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deprecation

My personal preference is to always immediately fix such a warning and keep up with the latest and greatest APIs if possible.

Comment: Deprecation doesn't *necessarily* mean that they plan to remove something.  It means that there's a newer API that is preferred for new development.  The `NSURLConnection` API, in particular, is so widely used that it *can't* realistically go away in the foreseeable future, because it would break too many apps.  In fact, I think I remember hearing that `NSURLConnection` is now a glorified wrapper around `NSURLSession`, meaning that Apple no longer has to maintain it separately, which IMO is an acknowledgement that the older API will be around for the long haul.

Comment: That's why I wrote that they were planning to remove it and I believe they actually did for NSURLConnection. But nevertheless all you said makes sense and is a good addition, thanks!

Comment: If my remove, you mean removed the underlying code, then, yes.  Just not the API.  :-)